# Format/terminology question about ROS camera calibration file

Tags: calibration, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a question about ROS calibration file, which usually looks like following:

image_width: 640

image_height: 480

camera_name: depth

camera_matrix:

rows: 3

cols: 3

data: [576.340422017257, 0, 315.229913874748, 0, 577.120041676589,
250.030883769157, 0, 0, 1]

distortion_model: plumb_bob

distortion_coefficients:

rows: 1

cols: 5

data: [-0.0286095107438031, 0.0222151550967861, 0.00317802383728588, -0.000592924755007265, 0]

rectification_matrix:

rows: 3

cols: 3

data: [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]

projection_matrix:

rows: 3

cols: 4

data: [571.976867675781, 0, 314.347170717498, 0, 0, 573.202819824219,
250.547239071138, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]

My question is: what is the difference between camera_matrix and projection_matrix.
They all looks like sort of "intrinsics matrix", but they are off a bit numerically.
How do I transform our intrinsics matrix from our customized calibration procedure into this format properly?

Thank you for any help!

Best,
Ranqi

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40661/format/terminology-question-about-ros-camera-calibration-file/) by [ranqi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2941/ranqi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-08-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The full definition of the [CameraInfo](http://ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/CameraInfo.html) message has a pretty good description of what each term means.

For a monocular camera, P and K will be the same. For a stereo pair:

> [Tx Ty 0]' is related to the position
> of the optical center of the second
> camera in the first camera's frame.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1